# Does a "rescale()" operation cause serialization?

Tags: apache-flink

If I call a `rescale()` operation in Flink, I assume that there is NO serialization/deserialization (since the data is not crossing nodes), right? Further, is it correct to assume that objects are not copied/deep copied when `rescale()` is called?

I ask because I'm passing some large objects, 99% of which are common between multiple threads, so it would be a tremendous RAM waste if the objects were recopied in each thread after a `rescale()`. Instead, all the different threads should point to the same single object in the java heap for that node.

(Of course, if I call a `rebalance`, I would expect that there would be ONE serialization of the common objects to the other nodes, even if there are dozens of threads on each of the other nodes? That is, on the other nodes, there should only be 1 copy of a common object that all the threads for that node can share, right?)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [rescale()](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStream.html#rescale--) documentation, there will be network traffic (and thus serialization/deserialization), just not as much as a `rebalance()`. But as several Flink committers have noted, data skew can make the reduction in network traffic insignificant compared to the cost of unbalanced data, which is why `rebalance()` is the default action when the stream topology changes.

Also, if you're passing around a lot of common data, then maybe look at using a broadcast stream to more efficiently share that across nodes.

Finally, it's conceptually easier to think about sub-tasks vs. threads. Each operator runs as a sub-task, which (on one Task Manager) is indeed being threaded, but the operator instances are separate, which means you don't have to worry about multi-threading at the operator level (unless you use class variables, which is usually a Bad Idea).